# Angular app routing during bootstrap in iframe

Tags: html, angular, angular-ui-router

I have an angular app running in an iframe. The html looks like this.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe src="http://localhost:9999?screen=two"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the path provided, I have added a query param 'screen'. There are three views available, routing is shown below.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'one', component: OneComponent },
  { path: 'two', component: TwoComponent },
  { path: '', component: AppComponent }
];
```

Within the angular app, I have resolved the component to be shown in `ngOnInit()` of `app.component.ts`

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const screen = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['screen'];
    console.log('main component loaded.');
    console.log(screen);
    this.router.navigate([screen]);
}
```

The problem is, the iframe always shows OneComponent until, I re-open the tab after changing the query param.
My questions are:

1. Why does this happen?
2. Is there a way I can make the screen change
   after only changing the query param and reloading, instead of
   reopening the tab?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the why but there is a fix to refresh the `iframe` automatically every time the query param changes.

```
<script>
    var _theframe = document.getElementById("theframe");
    theframe.contentWindow.location.href = theframe.src;
</script>
```